# Regex Based on conditions

Tags: angularjs, regex, phone-number

I am trying to write a directive, that passes the ng model of two fields, like mobile code and mobile number.

Where I am concating the ngmodels and where I am using a REGEX.

The conditions are like,
If the mobile code is 015x- the total number of mobile digits should be strictly 12

If the mobile code is 01xx or 01xxx - then the total number of digits will be 11 or 12.

The code is:

```
angular.module('Validation').directive('mobileNumberValidator', function () {
var MOBILE_NUMBER_REGX = /^(?:(?=015)[0-9]{12} | [0-9]{11,12} )$/;

return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
        mobilecode: '='
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        dovalidation();
        element.bind('blur', function () {
            scope.$apply(dovalidation);
        });

        function dovalidation() {
            ngModel.$validators.InvalidMobileNumber = function (modelValue, viewValue) {

                var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                var regexp = scope.mobilecode + value;
                if (regexp.length !== 0) {
                    return MOBILE_NUMBER_REGX.test(regexp);
                }

            };
        }
    }

};
});
```

But the RegEx doesn't work as expected. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
/^((015\d{9})|(01[0-46-9]\d{8,9}))$/
```

It means: `015` + 9 other digits OR `01` + not a 5 + 8-9 other digits.

Comment: What does the notation [0-46-9] mean? Is that an interval??

Comment: @Alamelu `[0-46-9]` means, match __one character__ that is either in the span of __0 to 4__ or in the span of __6 to 9__. Aka any one number but 5.

Comment: @RustyX  one scenario in the testing failed is when, I enter a mobile code which is 0186 of length 4 and the mobile number to be of length 8 which is total 12. Now if I increase the length of mobile code to 5, the regex doesnt throw error as the length is 13 (which is invalid).

Comment: The error is triggred only when I key in another number in the mobile number field. Should I trigger it on onblur.

Answer (score 0):

Rusty's pattern will work, but this one is better (faster, shorter):

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qR7XwA/3)

`/^01(?:[0-46-9]\d{8,9}|5\d{9})$/`

- no capture groups
- consolidate `01` start
- put shorter alternative pattern first

Comment: It did not work as expected :( The error triggered even if the length is 11 incase of 015.

Comment: @Alamelu Quite right, thanks for showing me my error.  It is fixed now.